# How to run multiple tests on different browsers simultaneously using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

How to run multiple tests on different browsers simultaneously using Selenium WebDriver?

I am working in java, I even tried selenium grid
Downloaded:  the selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar file

Even after the procedures,

`I am not able to execute these commands on the command prompt`

1. java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role hub -port 4444
2. java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node -hub ...

Any other alternative ??

Answer (score 1):

Grid does not run tests in parallel. You have to run your tests in parallel in order to take advantage of Grid.  Grid simply provides a mechanism to allow you distribute browser allocation via a master server.

How you configure your test framework is dependent on which framework you currently use (eg TestNG, JUnit)

Comment: Thanks Robbie,
I am actually trying to run the tests parallelly using selenium webdriver. I was randomly surfing through the posts and I landed up with selenium grid.
My main motive is to run multiple tests using the selenium webdriver, is there any way to do that ?

Comment: No, the parallelism does not come from grid or webdriver; neither have any concept of parallelism.  You either use a test framework which provides parallelism or write some multithreading code of your own

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium+TestNG combination for this 
just before a day i done a program that run firefox & chrome browse parallely